# Examples of nontrivial proofs by cases in which only one case is ever realized

Tags: proof-writing, big-list

For teaching reasons, I'm looking for examples of proofs that use a nontrivial case breakdown in which only one case is **ever** realized, and yet it is very hard to prove which case is the "real" one.  Let me give two examples of what I mean:

**Example 1:** There exist two irrational numbers $x,y$ such that $x^y$ is rational.

**Proof:** Consider two cases based on whether or not the number $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is rational.  In Case 1, assume it is rational, and so the theorem is satisfied by $x=y=\sqrt{2}$.  In Case 2, assume it is irrational, and so we can take $x=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$, giving $x^y = (\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}^2 = 2.$

The number $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is either rational or it is irrational, so only one case in this proof is the "real" one.  Nonetheless, this case breakdown is useful, since it seems to require Gelfond-Schneider (or related machinery) to actually establish which case is realized.

**Example 2:** The game of [Chomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp), played on a $100 \times 100$ chocolate bar, has a winning strategy for the first player.

**Proof:** Consider two cases based on whether or not there is a winning strategy for the first player that begins by chomping the minimal $1 \times 1$ corner square.  In Case 1, assume such a winning strategy exists; then clearly Player 1 has a winning strategy.  In Case 2, assume not, and so Player 2 has a winning response to the minimal $1 \times 1$ chomp, say by chomping an $a \times b$ block.  Then it follows that Player 1 has a winning strategy by chomping an $a \times b$ block as their first move.

Again, the minimal $1 \times 1$ chomp is either winning or it is not, but as far as I know it is open which case is "real."  This example generalizes to one subclass of [strategy-stealing proofs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument)

Ideal answers will have the property that the proof is simple, and yet it is very hard (or open) to establish which case is the one that always occurs.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a number $x$ that is either 0 or 1.   What is the value of $x(1-x)$? Case 1: Suppose $x=0$.  Then $x(1-x)=0$.  Case 2: Suppose $x=1$.  Then $x(1-x)=0$.  Which case is it?

Comment: $e + \pi$ is either rational or irrational, however it is not known if it is rational or not... Same with $e\pi.$ Although this is arguably a trivial case breakdown...

Comment: @Michael I'd consider your suggestion a non-example, since the natural logical expression would be "For all $x \in \{0, 1\}, x(1-x)=0$" and both cases are realized.  For your second point, the rules of Chomp are such that there are no ties.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I guess you're right that any open problem can be cast this way (Theorem: Reimann Hypothesis is true or false, Proof: In case 1 assume it's true ...).  I'll weasel out of that problem by saying I'm looking for more nontrivial-to-prove theorems :)

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but the strategy for Chomp on any square board is simple: the first player should take everything except for the row and column of the poisoned square. This leaves the second player no choice but to shorten either the remaining column or row, making them no longer of the same length. From then on the first player should shorten the other side to make them equal again. In the end, the equal row and column size will be $1$, leaving the poisoned square all that is left for the second player. It is only for non-square rectangles that chomp is interesting.